# Meaning of period in (. 123)

Tags: elisp, list, read

I learnt `. /path/to/file` in bash is used to execute a file. Just out of curiosity, I eval something like the following in Emacs

```
(. 123)
     ⇒ 123

(read "(. 123)")
     ⇒ 123
```

It looks like Emacs simply reads `(. 123)` as `123`, what happened?

Comment: `.` is not a function.  `.` is not a variable.  Nothing happened -- zip, zero, zilch, nada.

Comment: @lawlist It seems to be a bit more complicated than that. E.g. `qsdf` is not a function either, but `(qsdf 123)` yields `void function...`. And `(. 123 456)` yields a syntax error `". in wrong context"`.

Comment: Looks like an edge case in the reader to me...

Comment: Btw, the equivalent of bash's `.` (or `source`) in elisp is probably `load`.

Comment: `(. 123)` on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lisp_online.php gives `*** - READ from #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"main.lisp" @1>: token "." not allowed here`. In emacs: `(boundp '.)` → `nil` and `(fboundp '.)` → `nil`. I.e., the effect described by you is very strange!

Comment: Almost certainly to do with fixing up reading dotted pairs.

Answer (score 15):

> It looks like Emacs simply reads (. 123) as 123, what happened?

That's exactly what happened.  To back it up with sources:

```
if (ch == '.')
  {
    if (!NILP (tail))
      XSETCDR (tail, read0 (readcharfun));
    else
      val = read0 (readcharfun);
    read1 (readcharfun, &ch, 0);

    if (ch == ')')
      {
        if (doc_reference == 1)
          return make_number (0);
        if (doc_reference == 2 && INTEGERP (XCDR (val)))
          /* ... */
        return val;
      }
    invalid_syntax (". in wrong context");
  }
```

This is the special case for `read_list` in `lread.c`.  Normally a `.`
is treated by setting the cdr of the previously read tail by whatever
follows.  However in the case there is no tail (like when reading
`(. 123)`), the next thing is read and returned as is.  Personally,
I'd expect that to lead to an invalid syntax error, but I'm sure
someone put the special case there to work around peculiarly terrible
sources.  I've tried out how other Lisp interpreters behave for fun
and none of `csi`, `pil` and `sbcl` do permit reading this,  so it may
be worth a bug report.

edit: Guile behaves the same, MIT-Scheme doesn't.  There goes my theory of this behavior being a GNU thing...

Comment: Isn't Guile GNU as well?

Comment: Yes, but so is MIT-Scheme these days.

Comment: Please consider reporting an Emacs bug. This is not "normal" Lisp behavior. What's more, it seems to be undocumented behavior.

Comment: I reported this in [bug#24875](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24875).